# want to use between clause in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, between, in-subquery

i want the record of employee who applied leave form '2016-03-16' date to '2016-03-25' date. But when i will write my query in which i would mention the between clause in where condition,like i mention the date

```
select * from leave_form 
where from_date and to_date between '2016-03-16' and '2016-03-25' 
     and status='yes' and emp_code='K0209';
```

it will show  me result like

```
type, emp_code, rm_id, leave_bal, from_date, leave_from, to_date,   leave_to, number, leave_for, status, applied_date, pendays,  personal,
K0209, K0093, 10, 2016-03-16, full day, 2016-03-25, full day, 10, personal, yes, 2016-03-15,
```

but also when i will write my query like

```
 select * from leave_form 
 where from_date and to_date between '2016-03-17' and '2016-03-17' 
     and status='yes' and emp_code='K0209';
```

it have to show me the same result indicating that you have already applied for this dates.
i.e it will show the same result:

```
type, emp_code, rm_id, leave_bal, from_date, leave_from, to_date, leave_to, number, leave_for, status, applied_date, pendays
personal, K0209, K0093, 10, 2016-03-16, full day, 2016-03-25, full day, 10, personal, yes, 2016-03-15,
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this part of your request  does what you want it to do : `where from_date and to_date between` . I don't know the priorities of the different operators here, but I'm quite sure it does check that both columns contain dates between those specified later in the query.

Comment: not clear what you need...you are using between clause wrongly as there is two columns from_date and to_date....so you need to use 2 between clause for both fields otherwise you need to follow as @Harry suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. Does this help...

```
select * 
   from leave_form 
 where from_date  > '2016-03-16' 
   and to_date    < '2016-03-25' 
   and status   ='yes' 
   and emp_code ='K0209';
```